# Use rich Google authentication on Android with Social Login support in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, owin, google-authentication

I have an Android App talking to an ASP.NET Web API back-end. Android app offers SignIn with email address or SignIn with Google.

I am using Google's SDK for rich SignIn experience i.e. user doesn't need to provide credentials and directly opens rich dialog for authorization. I am able to get the access token and user profile. So far so good.

Coming to ASP.NET Web API external authentication. I understand that once I have access token, most likely the following needs to happen:

1. Android app calls Web API with Access Token to do ExternalSignIn
2. Web API processes the request and returns bearer token of SignedIn user.

   - validates access token
   - obtains user's login info from Google
   - check for existing local user. If not found, create one.
   - Generate bearer token for the local user (newly created or existing one)
   - Return it to the caller
3. Web API can now use bearer token to call protected APIs.

I have been studying OWIN Auth Server and all the auth/authz code that ASP.NET creates for external social accounts, it seems it is assuming app will use web flow for Google Sign-In and there will be auth cookie set by the Google OWIN middleware.

I have searched a lot, but couldn't find any good pointers on how to do it efficiently by using ASP.NET's built-in support for Google sign in.

Worst case, the alternative that I have in my mind is:

1. Create a Web API ExternalSignIn(string accessToken)
2. In the Web API, pretty much do what I mentioned above.

Comment: I have the same question!!1 Any solution?